# Cloud TPU tools not generating profile

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, google-cloud-tpu

I've followed the instructions on [Cloud TPU Tools](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools). Except for step 4 where you have to change --tpu_name to --tpu, things seem to work as expected.

What failed is the generation of the "Profile" tab. I executed

```
capture_tpu_profile --tpu_name=$TPU_NAME --logdir=${model_dir}
```

which produced

```
Welcome to the Cloud TPU Profiler v1.6.0
Starting to profile TPU traces for 2000 ms. Remaining attempt(s): 3
Limiting the number of trace events to 1000000
Profile session succeed for host(s):10.240.1.2
```

I refreshed/restarted the TensorBoard multiple times, but there's no "Profile" tab and clicking "Profile" from the dropdown menu returns no data generated.

Is this a known issue with the Cloud TPU profiler?

--Edit 1--

Profiler v 1.5.2 failed at collecting trace events.

```
Welcome to the Cloud TPU Profiler v1.5.2
Starting to profile TPU traces for 2000 ms. Remaining attempt(s): 3
Limiting the number of trace events to 1000000
No trace event is collected. Automatically retrying.

Starting to profile TPU traces for 2000 ms. Remaining attempt(s): 2
Limiting the number of trace events to 1000000
No trace event is collected. Automatically retrying.

Starting to profile TPU traces for 2000 ms. Remaining attempt(s): 1
Limiting the number of trace events to 1000000
No trace event is collected after 3 attempt(s). Perhaps, you want to try again (with more attempts?).
Tip: increase number of attempts with --num_tracing_attempts.
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try again using [Cloud TPU Profiler 1.5.2](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-tpu-profiler/1.5.2/#description)?

pip install cloud-tpu-profiler==1.5.2

The Cloud TPU profiler 1.6.0 and the worker list feature is only supported in the current master branch of tensorflow, while it is backward compatible to tf-1.8 when using the following command
capture_tpu_profile —service_addr=10.240.1.2 —logdir=${model_dir}

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. With Cloud TPU Profiler v1.6.0, at least it is possible to parse the trace event (see the output in the question). But with v1.5.2, the profiler fails to collect any trace event. The output of v 1.5.2 is added to the question. In addition, I don't think I can use the `service_addr` in your comment, so I used the `--tpu_name` instead.

Comment: If you start trace capture too early, the TPU may still be starting up and you may collect no trace event. You can add the --duration_ms flag and/or the --num_tracing_attempts flag to increase the profiling duration and automatically retry trace collection when there is no trace event collected: capture_tpu_profile --tpu_name=$TPU_NAME
--logdir=${model_dir} --duration_ms=60000 --num_tracing_attempts=10

Comment: Qiumin, thank you for following up with the issue. Maybe I didn't make it clear with my last comment: for the same ${model_dir}, v1.6.0 could succeed with the profile session, yet v1.5.2 failed. And both tries were performed well after the TPU completed its task, so it's unlikely b/c of premature capture. But I'll get it a try and report back. Thanks again!